# source for api 29 not getting download?

Tags: java, android

[image]

I am using this statement in my code:

`Toast.makeText(this,"Player 1 wins!", LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Android studio is showing error as shown in picture. Source for 'Api 29' not getting downloaded. All package are not available. How to resolve this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem with:

**Android Studio > File > Settings >appearance and behavior> System Settings > HTTP Proxy**

Check if you have any Proxy Configuration.

If not, try it:

> Open Android SDK Manager

1. Click on Tools.
2. Click on Android.
3. Click on SDK Manager
4. Update the SDK.

Then Sync ,Re-Build and Restart Your Project.

I hope It helps you!